# Can you add a background color to a table in bootstrap with built in classes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) is there any way you can use a built in bootstrap color scheme?  This code wouldn't work, and I have tried "Active" and "Success" for colors instead of `background-color`, but they didn't work.

```
<table class="table table-bordered background-color: white">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>example table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [`.table-striped`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-striped) class, that makes zebra style.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**OR**

if you want more than 2 colors you can use [Contextual classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes), which you can apply to `tr` or `td`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="active">John</td>
        <td class="success">Doe</td>
        <td class="danger">john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="warning">
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="info">
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Well I mentioned the Contextual classes, which they are in tables section in Bootstrap docs, the background aren't ;)

Answer (score 12):

Bootstrap has some built in [Contextual backgrounds](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds) which can be added to any element

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/united/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table bg-primary"><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>
<table class="table bg-success"><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>
<table class="table bg-info"><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>
<table class="table bg-warning"><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>
<table class="table bg-danger"><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>
```

Also, you're code example doesn't work because you're adding css in the `class` attribute vs the `style` attribute.. should look like this instead

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="background-color: white">
```